# Where is the online official documentation about <ng-content> tag in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I came across `<ng-content>` in Angular2 application.
I can't find any documentation [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/).
Where is the online official documentation about `<ng-content>` tag in Angular2?

Answer (score 9):

There is currently no page for `<ng-content>` in the official Angular documentation, though you can find a short mention of it within the guide for [Content projetion](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#content-projection), where it says:

> The `<ng-content>` tag is a placeholder for the external content. It tells Angular where to insert that content.

Answer (score 4):

It is a known issue that the `ngcontent class` is not documented. Many people have searched and not found it. You can find plenty of people complaining about this on Redit.

Although there are many references of `ngcontent` in the docs. For example on this page.

[Docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html) for `ngcontent` examples `ng-content`

> These are the styles we wrote, post-processed so that each selector is
>   augmented with _nghost or _ngcontent attribute selectors. These extra
>   selectors enable the scoping rules described in this guide.
>
> An element within a component's view has a _ngcontent attribute that
>   identifies to which host's emulated Shadow DOM this element belongs.

I think you are searching for `ng-content`. So search for `ngcontent` and you will find information and examples using the `ngcontent class`.